# Angular ui-router redirecting, not changing ui-view

Tags: html, angularjs, router, angular-ui-router

Here is my app.js:

```
 // Now set up the states
        $stateProvider
            .state('/', {
                url: "/",
                views: {
                    "top": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/top.html'
                    },
                    "content": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/content.html'
                    }
                    ,
                    "footer": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/footer.html'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('consultar', {
                url: "/consultar",
                views: {

                    "content": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/consultar.html'
                    }

                }
            })
```

In my top.html i have this part:

```
 <li><a href="./#/consultar">Consultar Protocolo <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
```

But, when i click in the link, its not chaging just the `<div class="content" ui-view="content"></div>`, it changes the whole page(showing only the content of the consultar.html)

why?

Here's my index.html:

```
<body>
<div class="top" ui-view="top"></div> //for the navbar
<div class="content" ui-view="content"></div> //for the content of clicked link in navbar
<div class="footer" ui-view="footer"></div> //if i need some extra info 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui-sref` instead, so your link looks like this:

```
<li><a ui-sref="consultar">Consultar Protocolo <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your should specify the parent for consultar view:

```
         .state('consultar', {
            url: "/consultar",
                parent: "/",
                views: {

                    "content": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/consultar.html'
                    }

                }
          })
```